# How to detect whether a scroll view in android is scrollable or not

Tags: android

In my code I used to scroll view. But it only gets active when elements of the screen are more than the screen size . I want to know if the scroll view is scrollable. our the elements of the fragment is more than the size of the screen or that view.

Comment: that is the default nature of the scroll to be more specific of the situation can you please share what you actually mean.

Comment: just add dummy data so that you can check weather your scrollview is working or not.